# How to align labels of multiple input fields vertically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two input fields for the user to fill namely `username` and `password`. This is how it looks like

[image]

Here is the code below for the same

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">          
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now I want the `Email` and `Password` to be aligned vertically just like the input fields are aligned.

I read about `form-control-static` but I am unable to see the effect here. I tried using it for the classes for `Email` and `Password` something like

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-2 form-control-static" for="pwd">Password:</label>
```

But I do not see any change. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I am using Bootstrap 3

Comment: You mean to say your *E* for `Email` and *P* for `Password` should start at the same point?

Comment: @ChiragJain yes exactly!

Comment: @ChiragJain however the input fields should continue to stay vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work as expected..., try verifying if you have made any css changes...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class=" col-sm-2 col-xs-3" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class=" col-sm-2 col-xs-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

UPDATE the control-label class is by default aligning items to the right on bigger screens.. to solve it you can remove it.. or use [bootstrap alingment classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#type-alignment)...

Comment: Umm I don't think so..try expanding the snippet to big screen or run it in any other online code editor. There is not vertical alignment between the two labels.

Comment: Good catch, you are right the problem is the control label class that aligns the labels to the left on bigger screens.., updating the answer..

Answer (score 1):

The above style is coming from Bootstrap 3 only, "Text-align:right"

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

If you want to align labels to left, override the above property in your code as follows:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
    .form-horizontal .control-label {
        text-align: left;
    }
```